# Is there a theme on xcode that replicates this?

Tags: xcode

I've stumbled across a screenshot with a colour scheme that I love. Does anyone have anything similar for xcode? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the color scheme from the [Announcing Source Code Pro Blog post from adobe](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html)

Somewhere in the comments user Woz says that the color scheme looks like [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). And finally on that site there is a link to the [Xcode 4 work in progress](https://github.com/brianmichel/solarized/tree/master/apple-xcode4-solarized) branch of solarized.

I haven't tried it yet.